# Window does not appear using Clojure on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, clojure

I'm working through "The Joy of Clojure" and got to a section about displaying some graphics in a window.  My interaction with the REPL is below.  According to the book, this should make a small window appear.  A window does not appear.

I'm running Mac OS X Mavericks.

```
nREPL server started on port 54014 on host 127.0.0.1 - nrepl://127.0.0.1:54014
REPL-y 0.3.1
Clojure 1.6.0
    Docs: (doc function-name-here)
          (find-doc "part-of-name-here")
  Source: (source function-name-here)
 Javadoc: (javadoc java-object-or-class-here)
    Exit: Control+D or (exit) or (quit)
 Results: Stored in vars *1, *2, *3, an exception in *e

user=> (def frame (java.awt.Frame.))
#'user/frame
user=> (.setVisible frame true)
nil
user=> (.setSize frame (java.awt.Dimension. 200 200))
nil
user=> frame
#<Frame java.awt.Frame[frame0,0,22,200x200,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,title=,resizable,normal]>
user=>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frame does launch, but it may not be very noticable since it will be a small empty frame when the forms that you specified are executed.

You should increase the size of the frame and then draw something conspicuous, e.g.:

```
(def frame (java.awt.Frame.))
(.setVisible frame true)
(.setSize frame (java.awt.Dimension. 400 400))
(def gfx (.getGraphics frame))
(.setColor gfx (java.awt.Color/GREEN))
(.fillOval gfx 100 100 200 300)
(.toFront frame)
```

Comment: That's the thing.  It doesn't show.  It's not visible with a green oval, and it's not in the tab switcher.

Comment: Well, it turns out the frame was behind a full screen window the whole time.  No amount of `(.toFront frame)` or Alt-Tab or Cmd-Tab changed that.  It wasn't until I made the frame a conspicuously large size that I noticed a small piece popping out below my terminal window and realized what was happening.